# My Eclipse Application UI is broken on few workstations

Tags: eclipse-rcp

When one of my cusomers run my application in WINDOWS7 envirionment they experienced following exceptions, though it never reproduced locally or with other customers.

The error messages are as follows (i copied 2 instances of the errors as a reference otherwise i see lot of such error messages in their log file), looks to me like jar signing problem, can somebody help me know how to resolve such problems (i never seen such problem with other customers using this application)?

```
!SESSION 2012-02-13 04:11:42.771 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=Build:    262
java.version=1.5.0_12
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86

This is a continuation of log file C:\Users\myuser\workspace\.metadata\.bak_0.log
Created Time: 2012-02-13 04:11:52.102

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.workbench 2 0 2012-02-13 04:11:52.102
!MESSAGE A handler conflict occurred.  This may disable some commands.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.ui.workbench 2 0 2012-02-13 04:11:52.102
!MESSAGE Conflict for 'com.cybermation.ejsentity.ui.views.navigator.EJSEntityNavigatorView':
HandlerActivation(commandId=com.cybermation.ejsentity.ui.views.navigator.EJSEntityNavigatorView,
    handler=org.eclipse.ui.internal.registry.ShowViewHandler@6245a4,
    expression=,sourcePriority=0)
HandlerActivation(commandId=com.cybermation.ejsentity.ui.views.navigator.EJSEntityNavigatorView,
    handler=org.eclipse.ui.internal.registry.ShowViewHandler@1ca4eb4,
    expression=,sourcePriority=0)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2012-02-16 07:59:08.157
!MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86".
!STACK 0
java.lang.SecurityException: The signature cannot be verified for this signer META-INF/ECLIPSE.RSA in this bundle: org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.bundlefile.DirBundleFile@1558d62
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.verifier.SignedBundleFile.setBundleFile(SignedBundleFile.java:495)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.verifier.SignedBundleHook.getVerifier(SignedBundleHook.java:161)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.verifier.SignedBundleHook.getVerifier(SignedBundleHook.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.about.AboutBundleData.isSigned(AboutBundleData.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.AboutPluginsDialog$2.run(AboutPluginsDialog.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
```

THanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The first error - the handler conflict - is due to the existence of two handlers for the same command id `com.cybermation.ejsentity.ui.views.navigator.EJSEntityNavigatorView`.

From the handler - `org.eclipse.ui.internal.registry.ShowViewHandler` - you can see that we are talking the about the automatically generated handler for all views.

So, my guess is that you accidentally declare the same view ID twice in the plug-ins.

The second exception is a different story... I think...